# Is there a way to create multiple Go files that each have their own main functions inside one folder?

Tags: go

I am trying to create a folder of Go files where each file is one small project that should be run separately. When I try to do this as I would in other languages, I get an error: "main is redeclared in this block". What would be the best way to have separately executed files with their own main functions in Go?

Comment: Put them in separate folders. Each folder can have at most one package, and the `main` package can have at most one `main`.

Comment: Exclude all of them from the build with `//go:build ignore` and run them via go run. But "the best way" is to have one package per folder.

Comment: That is - for beginners - an important question, why do you want to close it?

Answer (score 0):

No.

An executable requires and entry point, and an entry point function is

- a `func main()`, defined within
- a `package main`

And since a single package resides within a single directory . . . No.

You need a directory structure something like

- `/my-project`

  - `cmd`

    - `alpha`

      - `main.go`
    - `bravo`

      - `main.go`
    - `charlie`

      - `main.go`

Not that difficult.